# When first prototyping a new board game idea - how do you start?

Tags: game-design, prototyping

I've been working in online gaming for many years but i've always had a love for board gaming.  I'm a great believer in paper prototyping any game or feature too.

I wondered what are the major pitfalls or techniques that board game designers use when they come to designing a boardgame to methodically work through the problems they find?

Having the ideas is the easy bit, but what can I do to effectively work from prototype to completion?

Any tips are welcome.

Comment: This sounds extremely broad to me, but maybe someone can't point you towards some exiting resources.

Comment: @kinnith -- note the related questions list here.  There are probably some relevant ideas in them.  I, for one, am sorry that this was closed.  Maybe there should be a separate 'discussions.foo.SE' like there is a meta.foo.SE for every foo on stack exchange.  I get that they are looking for Q&A here, but you have all these people together with the interest and expertise, it's a shame to shut down open ended things like this without getting the really good stuff that I think would come out of it.  Maybe I'll put a post on meta.stackexchange about it.  Bookmarking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be too niche of an "answer" but I occasionally go to a Beer & Board Games event at a local pub where people in the group bring their games and it's like there's a mini board game library running for the night.

Anyhow, sometimes someone shows up with a "prototype" game and advertises that he's developing his board game and would like to play test it. It's basically small scale closed beta testing to help test and polish game mechanics. It also helps that he can rotate through pools of play testers rather than reuse the same group each time.

So basically, get your game into a "sort of playable" state and take it out to board game events or get friends to come play it then iterate based on how that goes. What you change and why is, of course, the tricky part. :p

Also, don't worry about NDAs or people "stealing your idea"... you have more important things to focus on.